# How to read text from an image when you know the font and size of the text

Tags: java, ocr

I'm working in Java and trying to read text from images.  I know the font and the size (Small, 8pt) of the text.  These aren't scanned images and the text will never be slanted or italicized etc.  I've looked into Java based OCRs, but I really don't need an entire OCR library/program and I would like to write it myself anyway.

My search to see if this has been asked already lead me here: [Text Extraction from an Image Using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026503/text-extraction-from-an-image-using-java). I don't really know how to go about region matching.

The solution I was trying was to first adjust contrast/brightness or otherwise get rid of anti-aliasing, then split the image up into images of characters using the empty vertical line of pixels between each character as a delimiter, then use some algorithm match each character individually.  The problem is I've found some pairs of letters do not have any space in between to determine where one starts and the other ends.

Here's an example of the text.  The 'f' characters are examples of characters that don't have space in between them.
[image]

Comment: Can you not simply take the "ff" as a character, use an algorithm to identify that and then split it to "f" "f" later?  In other words, treat the characters without a space as one character, giving you a more than 26 letter alphabet, and then split them later?

Comment: I thought of that as well. Notice too though that there is no space between 'f' and 'e.'  There may also be other letters/symbols that have that characteristic and therefore an infinite number of possible substrings that would have to be split appart again.

Answer (score 0):

if you do manage to find the first "f" why don't u stop and continue the search by giving it a checkpoint that you know of. To make it general for all the unwanted connections 
1. You can use the best matching checkpoint
2.you can go forward then when you lost a match go back and forth from the initial and final points you get by checkin them simelteniosly.